# Hibernate SequenceStyleGenerator ignores initial_value param

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, sequence, liquibase

I'm starting some new project and gonna use postgresql instead of MySql (as usual).

So, my `AbstractEntity` class id field now configured something like this

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "dynamicIdGenerator")
@GenericGenerator(
        name =  "dynamicIdGenerator",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator" ,
        parameters = {
                @Parameter(name = "prefer_sequence_per_entity", value = "true"),
                @Parameter(name = "sequence_per_entity_suffix", value = "_id_seq"),
                @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "100"),
                @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1")
        })
protected Long id;
```

Also, i'm using liquibase to create database table, for example:

```
<createTable tableName="audit_field_name">
        <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="BIGINT">
            <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true"/>
        </column> ...
    </createTable>
```

Everything is fine, i've got table `audit_field_name` and corresponding
 sequence `audit_field_name_id_sec`, but this sequence have default start value : 1. i.e. config `@Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "100")`
 was ignored and i have some troubles with that.

So, does anybody know how to use `SequenceStyleGenerator` and determine `initial_value` param?

Comment: What happens if you let Hibernate generate the tables (and sequence)? Maybe Hiberanate does not touch your sequence anymore if it is already there because liquibase already created it?

Comment: Well, liquibase is our architectural requirement, so i can't allow Hibernate to generate tables. But sequence are generated by  Hibernate, not by liquibase

Comment: I meant to only let it run for a test. It wasn't clear to me that hibernate creates the sequence and not liquibase. I guess then this a pure hibernate problem. Can't really help with that. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found the mistake. Hibernate doesn't generate the sequance (in my case) - liquibase do. And liquibase create sequance with default params, so the ontly way to set start value is to alter sequance